# Java program to open notepad in full screen/maximized

Tags: java, awt

I was writing a program to open notepad application from java code.
I was able to do it with below code:-

```
 String command = "notepad.exe"; 
 Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
 run.exec(command);
```

It opens the application but it doesn't open in maxzimized/full-screen mode.

Is there anyway in which notepad application can be opened in full-screen mode using java or in a specified size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can with the help of `Start` and `/Max` argument,

Code

```
Process p  = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c START /MAX notepad.exe");
```

**Caution**

The code wont work if you dont use `cmd /c` before the command and it will lead you to the  `java.io.IOException` because it cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to give a dynamic Mode capability :-

```
String cmd = "notepad.exe /C START /MAX";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd + args[0]);
```

Runtime example :-

```
java -cp . StartWindowMaximized notepad.exe
```